# Deleting users do not deletes coments

Tags: comments, users, customization

Hello I have bee trying to figure this one out without any luck. I am deleting users from my site, and selecting either `delete comments` or `attribute comments to:` options do nothing. The user does not show in dashboard->users but all their comments are there and/or not attributed to someone i chose. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Have those comments been made with those users logged into site and not merely using their details in comment form?

Comment: @Rarst yes you have to be logged in to leave a comment.